# Strange white-space above header

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, css, html

After implementing among others the Facebook Pixel, there is a strange white-space above the header of our magento website: https://www.oplader.com

Does anybody have any idea what this could be? Even with DevTools there is no way to find out.

Comment: This existing post actually helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php. I edited one .phtml on another computer this afternoon, which added the BOM character to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browser console, if you see header it would look fine:
[image]

But if you edit it's html you will see a special character here before header

[image]

Remove this special character and this strange space will remove

[image]

You need to look in your code something is printing that causing this

Comment: Unbelievable how you spotted it that quickly, thanks. My next challenge is how to find what code is printing this. It are 3 spaces (1 tab?) and I can't find any code that is printing it. Any less clean way to solve it for now?

Comment: I believe this should do the trick for now: `var text = $('.page-wrapper').html().replace('  ', '');
$('.page-wrapper').html(text);` You can't see the dot on Stackoverflow, but in the code it is there.

Comment: This could be a quick fix. But you need to find in code. something is defiantly printing